# Object someUrl#someHash has no method 'contains'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

The following code is giving me an error in Chrome. It seems that `window.location.href` does not return a String, but that seems crazy.

Here is the code:

```
var theUrl = "" + window.location.href;
var hashValue = theUrl.contains("#") ? theUrl.split('#')[1] : null; (This is line 6)
```

This returns the following error in Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object someUrl#someHash has no method 'contains' myFile.js:6

(anonymous function) faq.js:6
k jquery.min.js:2
l.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
p.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
D
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: also attempted with `document.URL` to no avail.

Comment: what does `typeof(window.location.href)` return ?

Comment: Can you make a repeatable jsfiddle.net test case?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Trying to now.

Comment: @lostsource It returns `string` all lower case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment the `String.contains` method appears to be only supported by Firefox 19

[String.contains - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains)

That page also mentions some incompatibilities with MooTools, maybe your problem is related. For the time being you can retrieve the hash value like this

```
var hashValue = window.location.hash.substr(1) || null;
```

Comment: For those of us confused like I was when testing in the console, stackoverflow exposes a shiv for `.contains()` to chrome.

Comment: You are the man! I come from a Java background so I just assume that all Java `String` functions are in Javascript. Apparently not a good assumption.

Comment: @Ben yeah that was confusing. code to mimic the `contains` method is using `indexOf` ... `function (f){ return -1 < this.indexOf(f) }`

Answer (score 4):

`.indexOf` might also be useful instead of `.contains`

```
hashValue = theUrl.indexOf('#') > -1 ? ... : ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

The string object does not have a function called "contains", what you can however use is the "indexOf" function which will return a value >= 0 if the string of your interest is found in the target string, -1 otherwise.

One more comment: You can get the hash value using window.location.hash, so instead of doing whatever you are doing above, you need to do something like this:

var hashValue = window.location.hash.substr(1) || null;